# Is there a Ruby on Rails host that supports FTP?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, ftp, system

I'd like to create a development integration server that's on the open internet, running a Ruby on Rails app. But I need FTP or SFTP access to this server, so I can upload files to the codebase via FTP.

Is there a good Rails host that allows FTP connections? The cloud providers like Heroku and Dotcloud just support pushing from source code or build files, it appears.

Thanks!

Comment: For integration testing, it can be very helpful to front end developers to be able to upload files and test ideas quickly. With FTP, front end devs can use our IDEs to push stuff up instantly and test from any browser, any computer. Pushing through version control, while great for staging and production servers, is too slow for integration testing

Answer (score 2):

If you have experience setting up a Linux box I'd suggest using a VPS service, like Linode (www.linode.com) for instance, that way you can pretty much have any service running that you want. And if you don't have experience, that's a great way to learn ;)

Answer (score 1):

If it's just for development, Dreamhost's shared hosting works well enough and is affordable. $8.95/month for unlimited domains and storage and bandwidth and it supports Rails via passenger/modruby. You get ssh and sftp access and you can schedule cron jobs too. Especially great for development since you can easily create and destroy apps and subdomains. Main downside is that you'll face a tough time if you need any custom gems or if you need a different version of ruby from what your host's passenger is using. Customer service is good though, and they can install custom gems or move you around between shared hosts if need be. I probably wouldn't dare to deploy a live Rails site on their (or anybody else's) shared plan though.

All that said, lately I've moved to Heroku for dev/staging instances. Not worrying about custom gems is a big plus, and since we deploy live on Heroku it's nice to have almost the exact same environment in staging as well as live. Heroku is free for single-dyno apps as long as you don't spend too much time in the heroku console. Pushing code from different branches to different instances becomes a piece of cake when you use heroku-san.

Comment: thanks for the thorough comment! But Heroku doesn't give me FTP or SFTP access, right? that's my prerequisite. Wish I could find that on a cloud provider like Dotcloud or Heroku